Opening another URL in previously opened tab
I am opening multiple URLs in same tab which works well once but as soon as I refresh the source page from where the new tab was opened it opens new tab, any workaround for this?
window.currentChild = false;

function openInTab($elm) {
    if (currentChild) currentChild.close();
    const child = window.open($elm.attr("href")+new Date(), "myWindowName", '');
    currentChild = child;

    //Scrope script in child windows
    child.frames.eval(`
    setInterval(function () {
        if (!window.opener.currentChild)
          window.opener.currentChild = window;
    }, 500);
  `);
  return false;
}

Scenario1:

click on Open In Tab link, it will open a new tab
again click on Open In Tab link, it will close the previously opened tab and open a new tab

Scenario2:

click on Open In Tab link, it will open a new tab
again click on Open In Tab link, it will close the previously opened tab and open a new tab
refresh the source jsfiddle page
click on Open In Tab link, it will open a new tab (Expected closing previously opened tab)

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/nitinjs/a1zd2kuh/11/
Another solution I tried
opening url in same tab named myWindowName
function OpenOnce($elm){
  var existingChildWindow = window.open($elm.attr("href")+new Date(), "myWindowName",'');

  if (existingChildWindow && !existingChildWindow.closed) {
      existingChildWindow.focus(); 
  }

  return false;
}

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/nitinjs/qbvpyud0/18/ (same behaviour on source page refresh)

Why are you closing anything there in the first place?

Sounds like an X/Y problem. What are you actually wanting to achieve? Why use frames at all since if your JS works scoped to the child frames, then the frame content must come from same origin, and then you can just use divs and ajax

You are calling openInTab from link's onclick handler. Why don't you just set <a target="myWindowName"> on the link itself? It should have exact same outcome, witout any JS (?)

I am quite impressed that the code works at all without giving errors too

@C3roe I want to make it appear as if it is opening in same tab

@myf see the url of opened tab, it is always a new url, to dynamically set a fresh url for a tag I am using the js

"I want to make it appear as if it is opening in same tab" - that is what window.open already does automatically, if you re-use the same window name.

@C3roe same behaviour is not observed when we refresh the source page strange


Scenario2: […] 3. refresh the source jsfiddle page […]

Keeping the reference to a child named target window from the reloaded source window is not possible: each reload is considered navigation that creates new browsing context that builds own relations.
If reloading the source window would not break bonds with the children windows, it would mean that basically any page could target any tab loaded as "myWindowName" and navigate it to any URL. It would be a security risk.

This should do exactly the same as your fiddle script; without (attempted) closing and re-opening:
<a
  href="http://www.bing.com"
  target="myWindowName"
  onclick="
   href = href.split('?')[0] + '?q=' + new Date()
  "
>Open in tab</a>

Reloading the window with this snippet creates new browsing context, so subsequent link click will target and re-use newly created tab.
